# how to set api request to google drive api using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, google-api, google-drive-api

I working on a google drive project but I am not able to send search parameters with Axios to google API
from frontend react

can any explain to me how to write queries like in google  drive api url

1. Search all files and folders by date
2. Find a file by size
3. Find all empty folders
4. Find a file by type such as ppt, image, etc

Axios request look like that

```
 axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?access_token='+accessToken+'&q=mimeType%3D%22application%2Fvnd.google-apps.folder%22').then(res=>{
    console.log(res)
    setFolders(res.data.files)
}).then(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: yes this api request show error ?

Comment: kindly show me how to send a proper axios request

Comment: The drive API documentation is very exhaustive with node.js examples. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3 S.O. is not a place to ask other to code for you but to ask how to solve error you're facing. In this particular case please show us how you tried to achieve at least the first problematic and people may then be able to help you.

Comment: I just want to know how to write queries

Comment: I need just one any API request to perform any query with axios  -Raymond Shafiee

Comment: @AirUniversity Hello just so i know what you are asking for. Are you asking how to do a an axios request?

Comment: yes how to do with axios request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how you can use the Google Drive API with axios for each of your questions:

1. Search all files and folders by date

Yes you can! you can use **createdTime** and **modifiedTime** filters (see more available query terms [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#file_properties))

2. Find a file by size

Yes, you can, but, you will need to return the size of the file/folder and filter the resulting files by specific size, you don't need to download the file, but it could be a little inefficient since you need to fetch the files first (use query filters to limit the results).

3. Find all empty folders

Yes, you can! but similar to the previous point, you need to iterate each folder and search files using the folder id, checking if files are empty.
Ensure you're filtering folders only by using mimeType filter **application/vnd.google-apps.folder**

4. Find a file by type such as ppt, image, etc

Use mimeType i.e **image/jpeg**

| Google drive search filters | [<kbd>View in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-71123422) |
| --- | --- |

```js
// Search all files and folders by date
const dateFilter = new Date('January 01, 2022').toISOString();

// 1. Search all files and folders by date
const filesFilteredByDate = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
    params: {
     q: `createdTime >= '${dateFilter}' or modifiedTime >= '${dateFilter}'`,
     fields: 'files(id,name,modifiedTime,createdTime,mimeType,size)',
     spaces: 'drive',
    },
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
  });

// 2. Find a file by size
const sizeInBytes = 1024;
const filesFilteredBySize = filesFilteredByDate.data.files.filter(file => Number(file.size || 0) >= sizeInBytes);

// 3. Find all empty folders
const emptyFoldersSearch = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
    params: {
      q: `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`,
      fields: 'files(id, name)',
      spaces: 'drive',
    },
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
    }
  });

const emptyFolders = [];

for await (const folder of emptyFoldersSearch.data.files) {
   const childrenResponse = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
      params: {
        folderId: folder.id,
        spaces: 'drive',
      },
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${googleClient.fusebit.credentials.access_token}`
      }
    });

  if (!childrenResponse.data.files.length) {
    emptyFolders.push(folder);
  }
}

// 4. Find a file by type such as ppt, image, etc
const mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
const filesFilteredByType = await axios.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files', {
    params:{
      q: `mimeType:'${mimeType}'`,
      fields: 'files(id,name,mimeType,size)',
      spaces: 'drive',
    },
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
  }
});

console.log(`Found ${filesFilteredByDate.data.files.length} files/folders created or modified at ${dateFilter}`);
console.log(`Files larger than ${sizeInBytes} bytes:`, filesFilteredBySize);
console.log(`Found ${emptyFolders.length} empty folders`);
console.log(`Found ${filesFilteredByType.data.files.length} images of type ${mimeType}'`);
```

Comment: `console.log(filesFilteredByDate.data.files.map(file => file.size));`  i try this to check fields but it show array of undefined. i think google api does not gives the requied fields as we provided in axios request

Comment: Yeah! there was an error in the code, fixed now, it was missing the params property, in Axios, Get query string params needs to use params :P it should work now.

Comment: `const childrenResponse = await drive.files.list({
    folderId: folder.id
  });`  where this drive is come from in search empty files?

Comment: Sorry, I was using the Node.js SDK at that part, but now the code example is fixed using Axios too :)

Comment: You you very much for providing a working example, you got me unstuck ! My problem was passing the headers field. I didn't understand that we could provide params and headers inside the same object for Axios.

Answer (score 2):

Axios  is not your problem the API does not support what you are trying to do for the most part.

> Search all files and folders by date

You cant really. Download them all and search locally

> Find a file by size

You cant.  Download them all and search locally

> Find all empty folders

Its not easy and will be a lot of requests but.  You could use q to only get folders and then make separate requests using parents and then see if there are any files returned.

> Find a file by type such as ppt, image, etc

Us the q parameter and search by mime type you will just need to google the correct mime type for the file you are looking for.

```
mimeType='application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'
```

You should have a look at the [Search terms refrence](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms#operators) documentation it will show you wnat you can search on.